# String data of n bytes in java

Tags: java, android, udp, byte, packet

I want to construct string data of 1,2,3...10...16.. bytes in java.
I need to send this data as UDP packets.
I can choose between  1,2,3...10...16.. bytes before sending.

My code is something like this:

```
byte[] byteData = new byte[]{65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74};
for (int index = 0; index < bytesSize; index++) {
    msgToServer = new String(new byte[] { byteData[index] });
    stringBuilder.append(msgToServer);
}
```

Am I in right direction?

Comment: Why are you converting it to a string at all? Why not just send the bytes? Packets are inherently binary data - I see no reason to introduce string conversions unnecessarily.

Comment: Data is send in byte form, and you can retrieve data using byte oriented stream.

Comment: Right! But just to check i am receiving the right data at other end.Using Above construction of 3 bytes gives me string as ABC.

Comment: What were you trying to achieve? In many cases serializing the object before sending it over network is far easier -- you don't have to deal with lower level complexities

Comment: Like i said, i need to make sure i received data @ other end properly and display it as string.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make sure that the data received at the other end is the same as the one you send you need to decide on various hashing algorithms and use the same. We use MD5 hash to ensure that the data integrity while sending bytes over the network. You need to find a light weight algorithm for mobile applications.